# Tensorflow Model is extremly slow (due to for loop in call method?)

Tags: performance, tensorflow, for-loop

I got the following model, which I am currently prototyping to generalize it further once it works sufficiently quick.

```
class FRAE(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, latent_dim, shape, ht, n1, n2, n3, n4, bypass=False, trainable=True,**kwargs):
    super(FRAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.shape = shape
    self.ht = ht
    self.buffer = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(1,shape[0] * self.ht), dtype=tf.float32))
    self.bypass = bypass
    self.quantizer = None
    self.trainable = trainable
    
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n1, activation='swish', input_shape=shape)
    self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n1, activation='swish')
    self.ls = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='swish')

    self.l3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n3, activation='swish')
    self.l4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n4, activation='swish')
    self.l5 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(shape[-1], activation='linear')


def get_config(self):
    config = super(FRAE,self).get_config().copy()
    config.update({'latent_dim':self.latent_dim, 'bypass':self.bypass, 'quantizer':self.quantizer, 
                   "encoder":self.encoder, "buffer":self.buffer,
                   'decoder':self.decoder,"ht":self.ht, "shape":self.shape, "name":self.name})        
    
    return config
      
def update_buffer(self, new_element):
    n = self.shape[0]
    new_element_expanded = tf.expand_dims(new_element, axis=0)
    self.buffer.assign(tf.keras.backend.concatenate([new_element_expanded, self.buffer[:, :-n]], axis=1))


    
def resetBuffer(self):
    self.buffer[:,:].assign(tf.zeros(shape=(1,self.shape[0] * self.ht), dtype=tf.float32))

    
@tf.function
def call(self, x):        
    if self.bypass is True:
        print("Bypassing FRAE", flush=True)
        return x
    else:
        x = tf.squeeze(x,axis=0)
        
        decoded = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=tf.shape(x)[0])
        for i in tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0]):
            xexpand = tf.expand_dims(x[i],axis=0)
            xin = tf.concat((xexpand, self.buffer), axis=1)

            encoded = self.ls(self.l2(self.l1(xin)))
            decin = tf.concat([encoded, self.buffer], axis=1)
            y = self.l5(self.l4(self.l3(decin)))
            decoded = decoded.write(i,y)
            i += 1
            self.update_buffer(tf.squeeze(y))
           
            
        tmp = tf.transpose(decoded.stack(),[1,0,2])
        return tmp
```

Due to the feedback of the decoder output to the input layers of both, encoder and decoder, I cannot vectorize like usual. Currently, the model is extremely slow unlike anything I have seen, although I use minilayers with 2 or 3 neurons. The inputs I am dealing with are 1 x 3999 x 8 tensors, so not that big. How can I make the model considerably faster? At the moment I need 25 seconds for 10 examples, which is way too slow for my application.

I profiled the code where I predict a very small slice of data. The picture shows the result. Does it show an obvious issue? [image: Profiling Prediction]

edit: it is just a special kind of recurrent network. It cannot be that these are THIS slow, I must do something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, I believe my code is correct. The mistake was running it on the GPU and not the CPU. When I run it on the CPU using     "with tf.device('/cpu:0'):" and additionally use @tf.function(experimental_compile=True), the model is sufficiently fast. However, I now experience a memory leak during training due to the model, but that is a different issue.